# let $f$ and $g$ be two non-zero linear functional on $V$ such that whenever $f(x)\geq0,$ we also have $g(x)\geq0.$ Which of the staements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ and let $f$ and $g$ be two non-zero linear functional on $V$ such that whenever $f(x)\geq0,$ we also have $g(x)\geq0.$ Which of the following staements are true (It may also happen that none is true)?
>
> $a.$$\ker(f)\subset\ker(g)$
>
> $b.$$\ker(f)=\ker(g)$
>
> $c.$$f=\alpha g$ for some $\alpha>0.$

I don't know how to start this question already this question is asked but I didn't get their answers so sorry for the worry can anyone please explain me detailedly...Thank you

Answer (score 4):

$f(x)=0$ implies $f(-x)=0$ too so $g(x) \geq 0$ and $g(-x)=-g(x) \geq 0$. Hence $g(x)=0$. Thus $ker (f) \subset \ker (g)$.

Now fix $v$ such that $f(v) \neq 0$. Given any $x$ let $y=x-cv$ where $c$ is chosen such that $f(y)=0$, i.e. $f(x)=cf(v)$ or $c=\frac {f(x)} {f(v)}$. Then $y \in ker (f) \subset \ker (g)$ so $g(y)=0$. This gives $g(x)=cg(v)=\frac {f(x)g(v)} {f(v)}$. In other words $g=af$ where $a=\frac {g(v)} {f(v)}$. We have proved the last part. Since $f$ and $g$ are non-zero we see that $a \neq 0$. It follows that $ker (f)=ker (g)$.

Comment: sir, how did you proved 2nd option ? is it by rank nullity theorem

Comment: @Gopinath I proved the third property before proving the second one. The second one follows immediately from the third. No need to consider any dimensions.

Comment: Sir, sir in the 1st line how f(x)=0 implies f(-x)=0 ? it is not always true

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are given to be **linear**. $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Comment: from this how you are concluding ker(f) is a subset of  ker(g) becoz you didn't choose any element in the ker(f)

Comment: sorry for the troubling sir

Comment: There is no difference between $f(x) =0$ and $x \in ker (f)$.  I chose $x$ with $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Sir last doubt in the option 2 proving how f(y)=0 or you assumed it? and how did you think this?